# Python: Calling a module in same directory

Tags: python, module, init

I have trouble importing a module in same directory.
Basically, here is my organization

```
alex (folder)
 |
 |- alex (folder)
 |   |- __init__.py
 |   |- commons.py
 |   |- KnowledgeBase.py
 |
 |- test.py
```

in my **init**.py file, I have the following lines to make import of commons & KnowledgeBase easier in test.py.
It appears to work.

```
from .KnowledgeBase import KnowledgeBase
from .commons import *
```

In my KnowledgeBase.py file, I have a class called KnowledgeBase.

In commons.py, I have different objects:

- a namedtuple called CDE
- an object called TimePeriod

And then, in test.py, I can call my objects this way.

```
import alex as al
do stuff with al.KnowledgeBase
do stuff with al.CDE
do stuff with al.TimePeriod
```

What doesn't work now.

I am calling in KnowledgeBase.py the module commons.py.

```
import alex as al
stuff with al.CDE ...
```

I get the following error message.

```
AttributeError: module 'alex' has no attribute 'CDE'
```

If I do it the traditional way:

```
import commons as AC
stuff with AC.CDE ...
```

I get the following error message.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commons'
```

And if I remove everything in the **init**.py file, it works, but then, I cannot use "easy module call" in test.py.

If I keep an empty **init**.py file, in test.py, instead of simply writing

```
import alex
```

I have to declare all imports:

```
from alex import KnowledgeBase
from alex import commons
```

Please, what can I do to keep the import of the different python modules in alex "simple" and at the same time, being able to import module from alex folder into other modules in alex folder?

I thank you in advance for your help.
Have a good afternoon,
Bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come back after having found the appropriate formatting.
In KnowledgeBase.py, the correct way to import functions or objects from commons is by typing:

```
from . import commons as AC
```